# ELK Integration with mern stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, elk

I am working on Mern stack project and I want to implement ELK stack in that project and also implement search functionality by Elasticsearch. I am confusing to how I can implement ELK in my existing application what exact steps for that I don't know and also confused to install ELK locally or on cloud server. For Logstash how would be logs will come from react js I am confused.

I tried ELK documentation but not understanding steps properly so I am expecting proper guidance to do this completely.